# How to obtain a list of installed packages based on a backup?

Tags: apt, package-management, backup

I have made a backup of my entire computer and I reinstalled the OS right now. I know I should have listed dpkg -l to obtain a list of packages, but I have not done so. I only made a tarball of the entire disk.

I wonder how I can find a list of packages based on this data. I would like to have the same packages installed that I had on my previous set-up. But there seems no longer a way to gain a list of packages, since I already reinstalled Ubuntu on the computer and only have the tarball back-up.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to chroot to your backup and then execute your command. This will require that you extract your backup to disk.

Suppose you extracted your backup to a directory called `backup` in your home folder. Then execute the following commands:

```
$ cd ~/backup
$ sudo chroot .
```

This should let you execute commands in the current terminal that use your backup system.
Then you could get a list of packages using `dpkg -l` or `dpkg --get-selections`

```
$ dpkg --get-selections > /package_list.txt
```

After you are done, just exit the chroot:

```
$ exit
```

You can then get the package listings in `~/backup/package_list.txt`.

I haven't tried this by myself (i don't have a backup to chroot) but it should work.